# Last row in the database

Tags: mysql

How do you get the last added record/row to the database in MySQL. I have to know this because I only want to update the last added row to the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have an ID column within your table you would do this by:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: can i use this in a mysqli update query in php? example
 $query = sprintf("UPDATE tblPlaces " ." SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " . " WHERE Id= **HERE must come the id of the last record;",

Comment: You could do something like:

UPDATE tblPlaces ..... WHERE Id = (SELECT id FROM tblPlaces ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 7):

if you have an auto-incrementing id you can do this

```
select * from your_table order by id desc limit 1
```

or even simpler

```
select max(id) from your_table
```

generally if you have a column in your table that indicates what your last record is do

```
select max(column_that_indicates_order) from your_table
```

if you do not have any column indicating what your last record was then you can't find it. Just selecting the first element without any order will not give the lastest entry last.

### Edit

To update your last record you can do this:

```
UPDATE tblPlaces SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' 
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: can i use this in a mysqli update query in php? example $query = sprintf("UPDATE tblPlaces " ." SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " . " WHERE Id= **HERE must come the id of the last record;"

Comment: you could do `UPDATE tblPlaces " ." SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " . " WHERE Id=(select max(id) from your_table)`

Comment: I fixed it, missing '' but he is not filling in any field

Comment: @Niels: The query itself looks ok. What is the error exactly? Do you have special characters in `%s`?

Comment: $query = sprintf("UPDATE tblPlaces  SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' WHERE Id='(select * from tbl_places order by Id desc limit 1)';",
I tried with this one, but he is not filling in LAT and LNG, just left than blank

Comment: $Juergen d THANKS! Problem solved! now the script also work when the numbers are not in locical order (1 3 4 7). It will alwasy update id 7

Answer (score 1):

This is the function for last inserted row when $conn, is the name of your connection. This is only good for last **single** row.

```
$thelastid=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

If you want to retrieve the last multiple rows, then you use
`select * from your_table order by id desc limit 1`

Comment: This would only work if the INSERT query was executed in the same PHP script, using the same connection link and immediately preceding the call to this function. What OP is asking is much broader. How do you get the most recently added record into a table?