# Automatically select an image

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a upload button so user's can select their avatars in my webisite. So far, I was able to make a directory in my php htdocs folder called

```
 'uploads/user_pic/'.$first_name.'_'.$last_name.'/'.'profile_pic'.'/'
```

However, in my html code that specifically calls up said directory above, it only takes in .png files. I know this because in my html code, when declaring the path for my image it says

```
  <img src = "uploads/user_pic/<?php echo $first_name.'_'.$last_name; ?>/profile_pic/profile_pic.png" class = "img-thumbnail" />
```

I need to know a way that makes html automatically just take an image inside a directory without needing the file ending. (Somewhat like how a .html file called index automatically gets called up). I already implemented a system that if the user wants to upload another photo, the directory get's automatically deleted, and then uploads the new photo.

Comment: Why not create a database table to store paths to user avatars? Takes a lot of complexity out of this issue

Comment: Yeah, but from user's perspective, they might want to upload a .jpg, or a .png. From my understanding paths must be either be labled as /profile_pic.png or /profile_pic.jpg. All I need to know is how I can make php or html just look inside a folder and pick that one image.

Comment: yeah, even with a simple database table with just an id,userID & link... when the user uploads or updates the profile picture, just insert/update the row with the path of the link and file type... as far as i'm aware you can get the file extension info of a file, but not guess at a file extension, unless you try .jpg first and if that fails, then try .png , but that seems like bad practice and wouldn't recommend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions of Liam G, I finally found a tutorial that would allow me to put the image paths on a database.

I would follow this tutorial to get the last row in the database (to get the most current image) and watch this video in order to do a sqli search.It's very useful also if you watch this video(2nd link).

[Last row in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550205/last-row-in-the-database) (How to access it in mysqli)

http://makitweb.com/upload-and-store-an-image-in-the-database-with-php/ (If you want to learn how to make a simple database that holds images).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYSu6FnE_VM (for newbies like me who didn't understand mysql and mysqli - guy speaks in forign language, but other than that, the code makes sense and you learn how to use the commands in the StackOverflow link Last row in the database).

Programming solution!

```
<?php
 //login information....

 // Create connection
 $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$your_dbname);
 $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select max(id) from your_table_name");
 $print_data = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);

$sql = "select name from images where id=".$print_data[0];
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$image = $row['name'];
$image_src ='assets/imagesfor_USERS/upload/'.$first_name.'_'.$last_name.'/'.$image;
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I wouldn't recommend this approach. Use a database or some other structure.

```
$path = 'uploads/user_pic/'.$first_name.'_'.$last_name.'/profile_pic/profile_pic.';
if(file_exists($path."png")){
    $userPic = $path."png";
}else if(file_exists($path."jpg")){
    $userPic = $path."jpg";
}else{
    $userPic = "default.png";
}

echo "<img src=\"$userPic\" class=\"img-thumbnail\"/>";
```

Comment: Is it possible you could personally suggest a tutorial for uploading images to a database? I was looking everywhere looking for a solution like yours.

Comment: You can upload images to a database, but I'd recommend just storing the paths of the images, do you have any database experience?

Comment: no. could you send me to the correct article on how to do the pathupload?

Comment: http://makitweb.com/upload-and-store-an-image-in-the-database-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

cant comment yet by why are you concatenating  the profile_pic part

and would it  not be easier to give the file a unique name not the directory?

'`uploads/user_pic/'.$first_name.'_'.$last_name.'/'.'profile_pic'.'/'`

Comment: the file name isn't the problem. It's the file ending. The images by user are stored individually inside their folders.